# How to treat different types in JSON response in golang or typed language in general

Tags: json, go

I am working on a project in golang and I need to work with JSON response. The thing is that a value in JSON coming from server can be something like

```
{person: "john"}
```

or

```
{person: {name:"john"}}
```

so to create a structure for capturing this I have a couple of options:

1) make person type as interface{}, but this will have redundant code later to work with the value

2) store values in new properties, like PersonAsString and PersonAsObject, this makes code bit more unpredictable as it meant to be used as a module for other developers

any other pros and cons for this? any other suggestions how to treat unknown type JSON fields?

Comment: There is only one way and that is to create `interface{}` that you have mentioned. And then use switch to get the value. If you don't know the JSON response you can only use `interface{}`.

Comment: This answer might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/49107090/5821354 on how to fetch value from interface using type assertion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to define a type with custom JSON marshal and unmarshal functions.

```
type Person string

func (p *Person) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    if strings.HasPrefix(string(*p),"{"){
        value := map[string]string{}
        json.Unmarshal(b,&value)
        *p = Person(value["name"])
    }else{
        *p = Person(b)
    }
    return nil
}

func (p Person) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return []byte(p),nil
}


type PersonStruct struct{
    Person  Person `json:"person"`
}

func main(){
    one := `{"person": "john"}`
    two := `{"person": {name:"john"}}`
    result := PersonStruct{}
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(one),&result)
    fmt.Println(result)
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(two),&result)
    fmt.Println(result)
}
```

Comment: This looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you have to use `interface{}`.

But with purpose to reduce complexity of your struct you can have one additional field like `NameValue` and fill this value after `json.Unmarshal` and assign value or from `person` either from `person.name`.

In your code you can loosely use `NameValue` which will always contain correct value.